# How to detect bending down person while sitting in front of laptop by camera laptop and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, face-detection

I'm new to images processing. I found many libraries such as track.js, brfv4 etc. can face detection. But about bending down a person while sitting. I can't find it. I need some suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Bending down whilst sitting? lol A face is a face, perhaps look for drastic changes in the vertices and triangles https://tastenkunst.github.io/brfv4_docs/#vertices

Comment: Maybe my English is not good lol. I'm trying to detection back bending with laptop camera. Thank you anyway @LawrenceCherone